# CS7036 C# How to solve error button onclick

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm using blazor project. I'm trying to import JavaScript function in onclick.

> Error  CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'element' of 'Index.AddDB(ElementReference, int)'

Line of error (onclick)

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%" @onclick="()=>AddDB()">Calculate</button>
```

C#

```
    string name = string.Empty;
IJSObjectReference module;
private ElementReference InNumberPatient;
private ElementReference InInterval;
private ElementReference InMHCProduct;
private ElementReference InComProduct;
private ElementReference InMHCTreatmentTime;
private ElementReference InComTreatmentTime;
private ElementReference InMHCDaysPerDressing;
private ElementReference InComDaysPerDressing;
private ElementReference InMHCLabourTime;
private ElementReference InComLabourTime;
private ElementReference InMHCDressingCost;
private ElementReference InComDressingCost;
private ElementReference InMHCOtherCost;
private ElementReference InComOtherCost;
private ElementReference InMHCLabourCost;
private ElementReference InComLabourCost;

async Task AddDB(ElementReference element)
{
    module = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./scripts/IndexedDB.js");
    await module.InvokeVoidAsync("IndexedDb", element);
    

}
```

Comment: What is the expected value of `clickedButton`?

Comment: @Llama expected the button to pass the ` input value` to JavaScript.

Comment: "input value" isn't an `int`.

Comment: @Llama ok I remove that clickedButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%" @onclick="()=>AddDB()">Calculate</button>
```

You should pass a parameter of type ElementReference to the AddDB method, like that:

```
@onclick="()=>AddDB(elementX)"
```

Note: the parameter `elementX` is of `ElementReference` type, defined in your code. It is accepted as `ElementReference element` in your `AddDB` method